# Drag Menu Item element from Submenu Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I am total noob in `Jquery`. I created submenu in `xhtml`.

```
<p:panelMenu style="width:200px" id="menus">
                <p:submenu label="Add Control" styleClass="ctl-tiered-submenu-1"
                    rendered="true">
                    <p:menuitem value="Bilance" actionListener="#{myIndexBean.addControl}"/>
                    <p:separator />
                    <p:menuitem value="Average Salary" />
                </p:submenu>
</p:panelMenu>
```

Now I want have draggable `MenuItem`. I created this using `JQuery`:

```
$(".ui-panelmenu-content").draggable({revert:true });
```

Now I have draggable `MenuItem`, but I can't move this element outside of `Submenu`. How I can correct this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 HTML    
<!Doctype html>
 <html>
 <body>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="javascript:void;" data-address="a.php">Blah</a>
   <li><a href="javascript:void;" data-address="b.php">Blah</a>
  <li><a href="javascript:void;" data-address="c.php">Blah</a>
  <li><a href="javascript:void;" data-address="d.php">Blah</a>
  <li><a href="javascript:void;" data-address="e.php">Blah</a>
  <li><a href="javascript:void;" data-address="f.php">Blah</a>
</ul>
<div class="ui-widget-header">
 <p>Drag a menu item over me!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>


   CSS
    ul li {
      display:inline-block;
      position:relative;
       text-align:center;
        }
    @media screen and (min-width:480px) {ul li{width:33.33%;}}
    @media screen and (max-width:479px) {ul li{width:50%;}}
      @media screen and (max-width:195px) {ul li{width:100%;}}
   ul li a {
      display:block;
     padding:20px 0;
    text-decoration:none;
   color: black;
    text-transform:uppercase;
      }
     ul li:nth-child(1) a{background-color: green;}
     ul li:nth-child(2) a{background-color: red;}
     ul li:nth-child(3) a{background-color: #ff8400;}
     ul li:nth-child(4) a{background-color: purple;}
     ul li:nth-child(5) a{background-color: #49a7f3;}
     ul li:nth-child(6) a{background-color: yellow; }
  .ui-widget-header {
   height:56px;
    padding:18px 0;
   margin:auto !important;
   text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
```

jQuery

```
   $(function () {
   $("ul li").draggable({
     snap: ".ui-widget-header",
    snapMode: "inner",
    revert: "invalid"
   });
      $(".ui-widget-header").droppable({
         accept: "li",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
           location = $(ui.draggable).children('a').data('address');
           }
        });
        $(window).resize(function () {
        var droppable = $('.ui-widget-header');
                 droppable.width($('li').outerWidth() -   parseInt(droppable.css('borderLeftWidth'), 10) -     parseInt(droppable.css('borderRightWidth'), 10));
   }).resize();
   });
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I want take submenu element outside , not inside